# Maximizing the sum of nonnegative functions.

Tags: optimization

I was trying to solve the problem [A maximization problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1090810/a-maximization-problem/) when I ask myself if the general problem

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{c}
 maximize\hspace{1cm} f(\mathbf{X})^p +g(\mathbf{X})^p \\
s.t. \hspace{1cm} \mathbf{X} \in K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m \times n},
\end{array}
\end{equation} is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
 \begin{array}{c}
 maximize\hspace{1cm} f(\mathbf{X}) +g(\mathbf{X}) \\
s.t. \hspace{1cm} \mathbf{X} \in K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{m \times n},
\end{array}
\end{equation} when the scalar functions $f(\mathbf{X})$ and $g(\mathbf{X})$ are nonnegative on $K$, and $p > 0$.

Is this true? If not,  how to find a counterexample?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $f(x)=(2-x)$ and $g(x)=\sqrt x$ for $x \in [0,2]$

Take $p=2$

$h_1(x)=f+g$

$h_2(x)=f^2+g^2$

$h_1$ is maximum for $x=\dfrac{1}{4}$ and $h_2$ is maximum for $x=0$ (edited after comment...), with its minimum for $\dfrac{3}{2}$

Comment: $x=3/2$ is the minimum of $h_2$, not the maximum.

Comment: @AlexSilva $h_1(0)=2$ while $h_1(1/4)=9/4>2$.

Comment: Yes! You're right. I have seen it. Thanks for the answer. :)